# Formula to search highest value related to a near match reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, lookup

I have a list of neutral references which change as per the date so

What I am looking for is a formula that will search Product and return the latest date.

e.g.,

```
A                            B
Product one 1 DEC 13    01/12/2013
Product one 2 DEC 13    02/12/2013
Product one 3 DEC 13    03/12/2013
Product two 4 JAN 14    04/12/2014
Product two 5 JAN 14    05/12/2014
```

Search "Product one" and return 3/12/2013 as a result.

I am having trouble as I am looking for near matches (as the references change with the date) and I am not sure how to only select the latest date that refers to a particular product.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the latest date always last?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please clarify what you mean “near matches”. 
I’m guessing that you mean, for example,
that “Product one 1 DEC 13” matches “Product one 2 DEC 13”.

If that’s right (or close enough to being right), create a “helper column” that contains strings that can be matched exactly; e.g., `C1` = `C2` = `C3` = “Product one”. 
If you need help with this, please describe *exactly* how your “near matches” work. 
For example, `=LEFT(A1, 11)` would work for the (limited and probably artificial)
examples you have given.

Now set cell `D1` to `=IF($C1=$C2, "", $C1)`.  This will display the invariant part of the product name (from Column `C`) on the last line of the block of lines for the product, and blank otherwise.  Now filter out the blanks, and you’re done.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a formula for you that should do the trick. For it to work you'll need to do the following:

1. In cell D1 you'll type your criteria. I entered 'Product One' (without the quotes)
2. In cell E1 enter the following formula then press 'Ctrl+Shift+Enter' instead of just enter

   =MAX(IF(LEFT(A1:A5,LEN(D1))=D1,B1:B5))